# Connect to a MS Access database (*.accdb)

Tags: import, databaselink

The *JDBC Connections* section of the help file http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/DatabaseConnections.html gives me the impression that I can connect to a MS Access Database (*.accdb) using the following statements:

```
<< DatabaseLink`;
conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["odbc", "MTData.accdb"]];
```

where *MTData.accdb* is the name of my database.  I have verified that the file does exist using  `FileNames[]`.  Upon executing the statements above, however, I receive the following error message:

> JDBC::error: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified ...".

Typing `JDBCDriverNames[]` gives a list with "*Microsoft Access(ODBC)*"

Would somebody please be able to clarify whether I should be able to access a MS Access database using these statements?  Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried accessing the database by providing a DSN (Data Source Name), created by opening the ODBC Source Administrator (as I have a 64-bit operating system, but 32-bit Office, I used the program at location  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe).  Executing the following code, where "MTDB" is the DSN:
`conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["odbc", "MTDB"]];`, 
I get the following error message:

> JDBC::error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN
>   contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Comment: If it's just a matter of forcing the use of a 32-bit JVM, you can launch one as follows. You probably already have a 32-bit Java installed at the following location, and if not, you can install one from java.com. ``Needs["JLink`"]; ReinstallJava[CommandLine->"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\javaw"]``.

Comment: @ToddGayley Thank-you!  This works - I am able to access the database using the data source name (created using C:/Windows/SysWOW64/odbcad32.exe) and using conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["odbc", "mydatasourcename"]];  Note however that I could not connect using a named connection.  Given that this question is marked a duplicate, perhaps it is worthwhile putting your answer in the other question.

Comment: I have added the above remark into that older question.